# Переключатели в виде точек для слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

Здравствуйте! На opencart установил модуль EC Slideshow (слайдер картинок). У этого слайдера есть стрелки для переключения слайдов(только вперед и назад), но необходимо реализовать переключения с помощью точек. Как можно переделать модуль чтобы вместо стрелок были точки? В opencart совсем новичек(

Comment: Какой именно модуль? Сайт или код? В том модуле, который я знаю, в настройках модуля (в админке сайта) в настройках есть показывать или нет пагинацию.

Comment: @Andrew Hobbit, А можете подсказать где именно это находится?

Comment: А Вы какой именно модуль используете? Какая версия ОС? Или код шаблона tpl модуля слайдшоу.

Comment: @Andrew Hobbit, сам модуль называется HOK Slider, ОС 2.1

Comment: @Andrew Hobbit, нашел как включить эту функцию. А как и где можно их теперь отредактировать?

Comment: Смотрите файлы /catalog/view/theme/default/template/module/hok_slider.tpl и файлы стилей revo.css